# PHP cURL | CURL not sending cookies with GET request

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm trying to send cookies with GET request. It works only for POST requests. This is my POST request function that works :

```
function post()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxxxxxxx.xx/dashboard/GetAdvertisersTable');
    $body = "force=true&query.id=&query.advertiser=";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

    //Handle cookies for the login
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "cookies.txt" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "cookies.txt" );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

And this is the GET request function :

```
function get()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxxxxxx.com/Reports/GetCampaignInsights?id=fqlwi7u3');
    //Handle cookies for the login
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "cookies.txt" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "cookies.txt" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

After debugging the header, I can't find the cookie field in the header

```
GET /Reports/GetCampaignInsights?id=fqlwi7u3 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxxxxx.com
Accept: */*
```

Comment: Try to change `dirname(__FILE__) . "cookies.txt"` to `dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt"` - there is no slash before cookies.txt

Comment: using https, you should include `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` - but I am not sure if that affects cookies handling